# Why can't I add an overload in a derived interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm trying to create a derived interface that adds a new overload to an existing method. But TypeScript won't let me.

Consider the following interface that allows adding two `number`s:

```
interface SimpleAdder {
  add(a: number, b: number): number;
}
```

Let's say I want to create a derived interface that -- in addition to `number`s -- also allows adding `bigint`s. I would expect the following code to work:

```
interface ExtendedAdder extends SimpleAdder {
  add(a: bigint, b: bigint): bigint;
}
```

This code gives the following error:

```
Interface 'ExtendedAdder' incorrectly extends interface 'SimpleAdder'.
  Types of property 'add' are incompatible.
    Type '(a: bigint, b: bigint) => bigint' is not assignable to type '(a: number, b: number) => number'.
      Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
        Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'bigint'.(2430)
```

TypeScript doesn't seem to understand that I'm trying to *add an overload*, not replace the method signature.

It does work if I explicitly repeat the inherited overload. But this seems redundant to me (especially in more complex read-world scenarios):

```
interface ExtendedAdder extends SimpleAdder {
  add(a: number, b: number): number; // Copied from SimpleAdder
  add(a: bigint, b: bigint): bigint;
}
```

Another workaround I found was to define `ExtendedAdder` as a type alias rather than an interface. But this approach lacks the clarity of a derived interface:

```
type ExtendedAdder = SimpleAdder & {
  add(a: bigint, b: bigint): bigint;
}
```

**Edit:** My actual code has nothing to do with adding numbers, and my actual function signatures are more complex. This question is strictly about adding an overload to an existing method through a derived interface, not about this particular use case.

Comment: Here https://catchts.com/math you can find an example how to do it

Comment: @captain-yossarian The "adder" use case was just an example to illustrate the problem with overloads in derived interfaces. I've edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: Please check if it helps https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UAUBDAXFAdgVwLYCMIAnAGinwxwOIEoEA+LPQogbgChRIoAhBZdOQCWAcyGZgZCsLES68RvlHjgHTuGgB5AG7EANgHsUAE3Ej+cAGS9WQA

Answer (score 0):

Here you have generic solution:

```js
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type A = (a: number, b: number) => number;
type B = (a: bigint, b: bigint) => bigint;
type C = (a: number[], b: string, c: string[]) => 42

type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any;
type AllFn = [A, B, C]

type Overloading<T extends ReadonlyArray<Fn>> = UnionToIntersection<T[number]>

type OverloadingParams<T extends ReadonlyArray<Fn>> = Parameters<T[number]>

const x: Overloading<AllFn> = (...arg: OverloadingParams<AllFn>) => null as any;

const result1 = x(2n, 2n) // bigint
const result2 = x(2, 2)// number
const result3 = x([1, 2], 'sd', ['sdf']) //42
const result4 = x(1, 'sd', ['sdf']) //expected error
const result5 = x([1], 2n, ['sdf']) //expected error
const result6 = x([1], 2, ['sdf']) //expected error
const result7 = x(1, 2,2) //expected error
```